# Delete Cache in iOS. Cocoa error 513

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, caching

My app have to download many image from web. So I want to provide a button to clear caches of this images.

- Are these images save in `/Library/Caches` ?

I Assuming that there are stored in the /Library/Caches. So I attempt to delete these files by:

```
filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSError *error;
[filemgr removeItemAtPath: [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] error:&error]
// OR
[filemgr removeItemAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Library/Caches"] error:&error];
```

Both are error with `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)` in iOS device, but worked in Simulator.

Thank you for answer!

Answer (score 1):

You cant remove "/Library/Caches". You need to remove all items in"/Library/Caches"

```
NSString *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
for (NSString *filePath in  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:path])
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath] error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove direct Cache folder. You have to parse every file from Cache folder and remove them.

Thanks.